# Prove each of the following conditions is sufficient to ensure that $f(x+y)≤f(x)+f(y)$

Tags: real-analysis

$f$ is increasing and $f$ satisfies $f(x)=0$ and $f(x)>0$ for all $x>0$.

Show that each of the following conditions is sufficient to ensure that $f(x+y)≤f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x,y≥0$.

- (a) $f$ has a second derivative satisfying $f''＜0$;
- (b) $f$ has a decreasing first derivative;
- (c) $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ is decreasing for $x>0$;

I know $a → b → c$.

I don't know how to prove $f(x+y)≤f(x)+f(y)$ using (c).

Comment: Try reading [this guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to typeset equations on this site. Once you learn it it's much easier (and typesets much nicer) than using unicode symbols.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: Assume (c). Then
$$x\frac{f(x+y)}{x+y}\le x\frac{f(x)}{x} $$
and
$$y\frac{f(x+y)}{x+y}\le y\frac{f(y)}{y}.$$