# Let $f:[0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ be increasing and satisfy $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)>0 \forall x>0$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions, derivatives, metric-spaces

Let $f:[0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ be increasing and satisfy $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)>0 
\forall x>0$. If $f$ also satisfies $f(x+y) \leq f(x)+f(y) \forall x,y \geq 0$, then $f \circ d$ is a metric whenever $d$ is metric. Show each of the following conditions is sufficient to ensure that $f(x+y) \leq f(x)+f(y) \forall x,y \geq 0$:

a) $f$ has a second derivative satisfying $f'' \leq 0$;

b) $f$ has a decreasing first derivative.

c) $f(x)/x$ is decreasing for $x>0$.

**My Work Thus Far:**

Let $g(x)=f(x)x$, for $x>0$. According to the question we have that $f''<0$ then $f$ has a decreasing first derivative, meaning $f'$ is decreasing. Now, taking the derivative of $g$ yields: $g'(x)=xf'(x)-f(x)x^2=f'(x)x-f(x)x^2$, where $x>0$.

I know that $-f(x)x^2$ is decreasing, but how do I know for sure that $f'(x)x$ is decreasing so I can deduce that $g'(x)<0, \forall x>0$ and that $g(x)$ is a decreasing function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We assume that (a) or (b) holds. Let $x,y\in[0,\infty)$. If $x=0$
or $y=0$, we clearly have $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ because $f(0)=0$.
Consider the case that $x>0$ and $y>0$. Without loss of generality, we may assume that $x\leq y$. By mean-value theorem, there
exist $\xi\in(y,x+y)$ and $\eta\in(0,x)$ such that $f(x+y)-f(y)=f'(\xi)x$
and $f(x)-f(0)=f'(\eta)x$. Note that $\eta < \xi$, so by (a) or (b), we have $f'(\eta)\geq f'(\xi)$. Thererfore

\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & f(x+y)-f(x)-f(y)\\
 & = & [f(x+y)-f(y)]-[f(x)-f(0)]\\
 & = & [f'(\xi)-f'(\eta)]x\\
 & \leq & 0.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

By $c$ you have $f(x+y)\cdot(x+y)\leq f(x)\cdot x$ and $f(x+y)\cdot(x+y)\leq f(y)\cdot y$. Equivalently: $$f(x+y)\cdot\dfrac{x+y}x\leq f(x), \  f(x+y)\cdot\dfrac{x+y}{y}\leq f(y)$$

Summing both inequalities gives: $$f(x+y)\left(\dfrac{x+y}{x}+\dfrac{x+y}{y}\right)\leq f(x)+f(y)$$
From here you can conclude expanding and aplying AM-GM inequality.

Comment: sorry for inconvenience in c its f(x)/x is decreasing  ..

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1916031/prove-each-of-the-following-conditions-is-sufficient-to-ensure-that-fxy%e2%89%a4fx?rq=1